# Javascriptを使って、画面で入力された日付スラッシュ区切りにしたい。

Tags: javascript

下記のような処理で、HTMLに８桁の日付を入力後にマウスポインタが離れた時に、JavaScriptでスラッシュ区切りになるような処理を追加したいです。

**HTML**

```
<body>
<form id="formId" name="formName" action="cgi-bin/abc.cgi" method="post">
<p>
誕生日：<input type="num" id="birth" name="birth" maxlength="8" max="21000000">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="送信する" onclick="onButtonClick()">
<input type="reset" value="入力内容をリセットする">
</p>
</form>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function onButtonClick() {
    var str= document.forms.formId.birth.value;
　　var date = toDate(str);
}

function toDate (str) {
  var arr = (str.substr(0, 4) + '/' + str.substr(4, 2) + '/' + str.substr(6, 2)).split('/');
  return arr;
}
```

しかし、toDateの処理で文字列の連結がうまくいきません。なぜでしょうか？すみませんが、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: ぱっと見では問題ないように見えます。どういう入力に対してどういう結果を期待したけど実際はどういう結果になるか書いてください。

Comment: たとえば入力値が 20191121の場合の期待値は2019/11/21です。実際は2019,11,21となります。（JSBinでalert関数を使用して確認しました。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

提示されている`toDate()`関数は正しくできあがった結果を`split('/')`して配列にしています。この配列をそのまま文字列化するとカンマ区切りになります。

`split()`しなければよいと思います。

```
function toDate (str) {
  return str.substr(0, 4) + '/' + str.substr(4, 2) + '/' + str.substr(6, 2);
}
```

Comment: 期待通りの結果になりました！ありがとうございます。